# How do I add an element inside a list which is inside a list?

Tags: python, list

```
l = [1,2,3,[4,5,6]]
```

I want

```
l = [1,2,3,[4,5,6,7]]
```

Now I want to add 7 in the list which is inside the list.

I applied the same logic as accessing `[3][3]`

```
l.insert("index","value")  #syntax

l.insert([3][3],7)
```

But it isn't working. I couldn't solve it with append as well.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add a 7 to the element at index 3 in `l`.

That is:

```
l[3].append(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
l[3].insert(3,7)
```

Comment: I think that this will add "7" at 3th position in this list.

Comment: l[3].insert(3,7)  --> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7]]

Comment: Sure. That works in this case. But if you would like to repeat that you would get:
l[3].insert(3,8) --> [1,2,3, [4,5,6,8,7]. 

Therefore I think append is better as it adds value at the end of the list

Comment: sure append is the way I would go as well. But he was using insert in his question. So I assume he want to add it in a specific position.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with your approach? In the `insert(index, value)` method the `index` should be *an integer*. The `[3][3]` you are passing, is not an integer. Moreover, it is not even a valid value (meaning, you can't write eg `x = [3][3]`.

The `[i]` after an object calls its `__getitem__` method internally. So, what you are trying to do is

- get the element `3` of the initial list
- hope that what you get is a list
- insert on position `3` of that list

So, you can do that

```
inner_list = mylist[3]
inner_list.insert(3, 7)
```

or, more compactly `mylist[3].insert(3, 7)`

If you want to insert at the last position, you could as well write `mylist[3].append(7)`

Answer (score 0):

Here `l[3][3]` is an int. Ofcouse it will not work as there are no built-ins defined such as `insert` and `append` on `int`

While `l[3]` is of `list` type so it supports both of those functions

`l[3].append(7)`  or `l[3].insert(3,7)`

Also lists are mutable type so making a change in inner `list` will be reflected in the outer list as well. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can access to that 7 with:

```
l[3][3]
```

Comment: OP wants to add the element. Not access it.